# NodeJS write base64 encoded image to file

Tags: node.js, image, image-processing, express, base64

I have searched and tried all of the solutions at stackoverflow but none of them seems working at my instance. Basically I have an image, edited by html5 canvas, upload from client and I need to save it to disk, but unfortunately I can't open the file that I just saved. (I am using Windows 7)

My code:

```
var base64Data = req.body.image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|gif|jpeg);base64,/,'');
require('fs').writeFile('public/aboutToGiveUp.png', new Buffer(base64Data, 'base64'));
```

Comment: How you are trying to open the file? can you show the URL?

Comment: We added `app.use(express.static('public'));` so no need to add public in the url. please check the url once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got same bug, it's because of incorrect `url` path, You may added `app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`, so no need to add the `public` in the url, check your url path once.

working sample :

- `url = req.protocol+'://'+req.headers.host+"/"+filename;`
- `url = req.protocol+'://'+req.headers.host+"/images/"+filename;` // its in `public/images`

Answer (score 0):

Try using ./public/aboutToGiveUp.png or make sure that the path is relative to the file containing this code.

Comment: The path containing the file but it's unable to be opened.